# Tabula not reading my pdf/all data comes in as blank

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

I'm trying to take this pdf: https://www.occ.gov/topics/charters-and-licensing/weekly-bulletin/2023/wb-11052023-11112023.pdf and export as a csv with the columns "ACTION", "DATE", "BANK NAME", "LOCATION", "CITY", "STATE"

My code is as follows:

```py
import tabula
import pandas as pd


pdf_path = '*pdf file path*'

# Read PDF into a list of DataFrame
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='2', multiple_tables=True)

# Concatenate DataFrames into a single DataFrame
df = pd.concat(dfs)

# Specify the columns to keep
columns_to_keep = ["ACTION", "DATE", "TYPE",  "BANK NAME", "LOCATION", "CITY", "STATE"]

# Select only the relevant columns
df = df[columns_to_keep]

# Drop rows with all NaN values
#df = df.dropna(how='all')

# Write the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)

print("CSV file generated successfully.")
```

This is able to generate the headers fine for my csv, but the data comes in empty. Anyone have experience with this? Right now, just testing with page 2 but would ideally want the whole pdf.

Tried tabula functions but output is blank